# How can I make my command history start counting from 0

Tags: 11.04, history

If I type the following:

```
history -c
history
```

I get `1110 history`.

Why does clearing the command history not reset the counting to 1 and how can I reset the count?

Note: It is resetting the number, just not to 1. If I type 5 commands, the number changes to 1114 but `history -c` only resets it to 1110.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `bash` man page:

> On startup, the history is initialized
>   from the file named by the variable
>   HISTFILE (default ~/.bash_history)...
>
> When an interactive shell exits, the
>   last $HISTSIZE lines are copied from
>   the history list to $HISTFILE.  If the
>   histappend shell option is enabled
>   (see  the  description  of  shopt 
>   under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below),
>   the lines are appended to the history
>   file, otherwise the history file is
>   overwritten...

So, only on exit the file `~/.bash_history` is updated, and if `histappend` is set, the default, that file is not overwritten.

My suggestion, remove `~/.bash_history`, then perform `history -c`.